# How to show file type of featured image?

Tags: images, featured-post

How to show file type of featured image in post on single.php?

For example:
Featured image type is: ".jpg"

I can get mime-type, like "image/jpeg".

It could be also some check of image mime-type first, for example if image mime-type is "image/jpeg" then echo ".jpg" if it is "image/gif" echo ".gif".

Comment: Now people are answering the question in two different places on the same site. Please read [ask] _asap_.

Comment: Also this is close to a duplicate of a question that you asked a year ago. Why did you not follow up on the old one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to show the File type of featured image. then try the below code.

```
<?php
    $id1 = get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID);
    $type =  get_post_mime_type( $id1 );
    $mime_type = explode('/', $type);
    $type = '.'.$mime_type['1'];
    echo $type;
?>
```

It will display the exact extension that you want ".jpeg" from "image/jpeg"
Here "$post->ID" is current post id (or the id of the post whose featured image you want ).
Check if it works for you.

Comment: Thank you, it works. Just one note, it shows ".jpeg" for image which is ".jpg"? For other extensions like ".jpeg", ".gif", ".png" it shows exact extension.

Comment: Yes, it will work for all. I choose one just for example

Comment: Yes, it works for all extensions. Is it possible for you to make it show ".jpg" for ".jpg" file, instead of ".jpeg" for ".jpg" file?

Comment: It will return ".jpg" from "image/jpg" and ".jpeg" from "image/jpeg", ".png" from "image/png".

Comment: When I upload image with extension ".jpg" it returns ".jpeg". Also I checked with `echo get_post(get_post_thumbnail_id())->post_mime_type` and I get "image/jpeg" for image with just ".jpg" extension. Any idea why?